# Strange response from a SOAP Client for a given WSDL in JAVA

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

Ok so i have to make a SOAP Client for a given WSDL in JAVA as the title says.
Now i build it with NetBeans and the issue is that when i run it and put in the IP that i want i get the following response 
"net.webservicex.GeoIP@564809be"

I tested the WSDL at their site and for the same IP i get the following

```
<GeoIP xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.webservicex.net/">
<ReturnCode>1</ReturnCode>
<IP>178.128.33.188</IP>
<ReturnCodeDetails>Success</ReturnCodeDetails>
<CountryName>Greece</CountryName>
<CountryCode>GRC</CountryCode>
</GeoIP>
```

Any ideas?? While i have to "decode" the message in order to be printed out normally?
THanks in advance

Here's the code of the client

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the IP Adress");
        InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);
        String ipad = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(getGeoIP(ipad));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Geoipad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private static GeoIP getGeoIP(java.lang.String ipAddress) {
    net.webservicex.GeoIPService service = new net.webservicex.GeoIPService();
    net.webservicex.GeoIPServiceSoap port = service.getGeoIPServiceSoap();
    return port.getGeoIP(ipAddress);
```

Comment: Please provide the code you were running, it might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`net.webservicex.GeoIP@564809be`
It seems you are printing the object's reference (the `net.webservicex.GeoIP` has not overriden `toString`). Don't they have some `String getIP()` to get the IP?

Comment: not that i see of...i posted the client code above if it helps

Comment: @LefterisD.Lalos:You are printing `GeoIP`.

Comment: @LefterisD.Lalos:I mean you should use the corresponding getters to print the information

Comment: Not the ipAddress i'm expecting to see but the Country of the IP address. I'm new to SOAP so i'm sorry if something is really obvious and i don't see it

Comment: @LefterisD.Lalos:This has nothing to do with `SOAP`.You are doing `System.out.println(GeoIP)`.This uses the default's `Object.toString()` which prints the object's reference info.You should use each correspoding `getter` provided by `GeoIP` to see information of interest

Answer (score 0):

the following works

```
GeoIPService ipService = new GeoIPService();
GeoIPServiceSoap geoIPServiceSoap = ipService.getGeoIPServiceSoap();
GeoIP geoIp = geoIPServiceSoap.getGeoIP("10.34.55.1");
System.out.println(geoIp.getCountryName());
```